# Manual bumping of a question

Tags: discussion

Quick inquiry about proper behavior on this stack exchange. I wrote a question recently and posted it during a period where not a lot of active users are active. Thus, my question didn't receive a lot of views or answers.

My question was, is there a proper behavior regarding question bumping? I know that editing my question will put it back on top of the queue, but I don't want to infringe on any written or non written rules.

Comment: In this situation, if you want to drag attention to your question, your best bet is probably to set a bounty on it, even a small one.

Comment: This is your chance to get the elusive "Tumbleweed" badge. I have two, but on other sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needless edits for the sake of bumping will not be seen in a positive light. That said, we wouldn't know your simply bumping unless the edits were numerous or you posted this.

The system also doesn't really respond well to bumping. Many people look for new unanswered questions. I rarely look at the front page/hot questions. Instead I look at the new question page.

This is because stack exchange does not function like a typical forum.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter, if its a good question, you've tagged it appropriately and there are a reasonable amount of 'experts', someone will look at it. If your question is getting views and you aren't getting answers, it's probably a good time to see if it's a well written, answerable question. If it isn't then you might want to change that.

Another possibility is you've written a question that doesn't have a lot of expertise in the area, most people here do circuit design.

Comment: In the case of the question I asked, I think that the question is borderline firmware/software and there won't be a lot of expertise regarding that here. I still had useful comments on it at the end of the day.